# maven plugin cucumber-serenity-testlink-integratio could not be resolved

Tags: maven, cucumber, pom.xml, testlink, cucumber-serenity

I'm trying to integrate cucumber and Testlink, I'm using this tutorial [tutorial link](https://github.com/bliblidotcom/cucumber-serenity-testlink-integration)

it says I need to add a plugin in my pom file, after adding all the things described in the tutorial I tried to run ***mvn clean verify*** in terminal. here is a piece of logs

```
   'build.plugins.plugin.version' for com.blibli.oss.qa.util:cucumber-serenity-testlink-integration must be a valid version but is '${serenity.testlink.integration.version}'
```

then I changed version to

```
<version>4.0.0</version>
```

and I got this

```
Plugin com.blibli.oss.qa.util:cucumber-serenity-testlink-integration:4.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find com.blibli.oss.qa.util:cucumber-serenity-testlink-integration:jar:4.0.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
```

please help me, I have no idea what to do

I add my pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ru.atconsulting.qa</groupId>
    <artifactId>b2c-automated-testing</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>B2cAutomatedTesting</name>
    <description>Project for automating mobile testing</description>

    <properties>
        <serenity.version>2.0.30</serenity.version>
        <serenity.maven.version>2.0.34</serenity.maven.version>
        <serenity.cucumber.version>1.9.23</serenity.cucumber.version>
        <serenity.rest.assured.version>1.5.3</serenity.rest.assured.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <groovy.version>2.4.4</groovy.version>
        <gson.version>2.8.0</gson.version>
        <maven.jar.plugin.version>2.5</maven.jar.plugin.version>
        <maven.compiler.plugin.version>3.1</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
        <maven.surefire.plugin.version>2.19.1</maven.surefire.plugin.version>
        <maven.failsafe.plugin.version>2.18</maven.failsafe.plugin.version>
        <org.json.version>20160810</org.json.version>
        <xmlunit.version>1.6</xmlunit.version>
        <trimou.core.version>2.2.1.Final</trimou.core.version>
        <trimou.extension.gson>2.2.1.Final</trimou.extension.gson>
        <commons.net.version>3.6</commons.net.version>
        <ojdbc6.version>11.2.0.4.0-atlassian-hosted</ojdbc6.version>
        <sql2o.version>1.5.4</sql2o.version>
        <mysql.version>5.1.39</mysql.version>
        <mssql.version>6.1.0.jre8</mssql.version>
        <postgresql.version>9.4.1208-jdbc42-atlassian-hosted</postgresql.version>
        <checkstyle.plugin.version>2.17</checkstyle.plugin.version>
        <checkstyle.version>7.7</checkstyle.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-cucumber</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.rest.assured.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>${groovy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>${org.json.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xmlunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlunit</artifactId>
            <version>${xmlunit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.trimou</groupId>
            <artifactId>trimou-core</artifactId>
            <version>${trimou.core.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.trimou</groupId>
            <artifactId>trimou-extension-gson</artifactId>
            <version>${trimou.extension.gson}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
            <version>${commons.net.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>${ojdbc6.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sql2o</groupId>
            <artifactId>sql2o</artifactId>
            <version>${sql2o.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.blibli.oss.qa.util/cucumber-serenity-testlink-integration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.blibli.oss.qa.util</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-serenity-testlink-integration</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${mssql.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.testlink.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>testlink-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
                <dependency>
            <groupId>com.testlink.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlrpc-common</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
                <dependency>
            <groupId>com.testlink.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlrpc-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
                <dependency>
            <groupId>com.testlink.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>ws-commons-util</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <defaultGoal>validate</defaultGoal>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
                            <groupId>com.blibli.oss.qa.util</groupId>
                            <artifactId>cucumber-serenity-testlink-integration</artifactId>
                            <version>4.0.0</version>
                            <executions>
                                <execution>
                                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>testlink-serenity</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                    <configuration>
                                        <testlinkURL>http://mapp-dev-web.corp.mvideo.ru/lib/api/xmlrpc/v1/xmlrpc.php</testlinkURL>
                                        <devKey>a08829cc000a14c4bc84dcb14449e6ff</devKey>
                                        <projectName>Mvideo_App</projectName>
                                        <testPlanName>test_auto</testPlanName>
                                        <buildName>test_buil</buildName>
                                        <platformName>ios</platformName>
                                    </configuration>
                                </execution>
                            </executions>
                        </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.jar.plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <testSource>${java.version}</testSource>
                    <testTarget>${java.version}</testTarget>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.surefire.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>${skip.test}</skip>
                    <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${serenity.maven.version}</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
                        <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
                        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>serenity-reports</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${checkstyle.plugin.version}</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
                        <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
                        <version>${checkstyle.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>src/test/resources/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                    <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                    <failsOnError>false</failsOnError>
                    <failOnViolation>false</failOnViolation>
                    <outputFileFormat>xml</outputFileFormat>
                    <sourceDirectory>src/test/java/behavior/steps</sourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.failsafe.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    <includes>
                        <include>runner/*.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Maven Central Repository</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>atlassian-public</id>
            <url>https://packages.atlassian.com/mvn/maven-external/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
            </releases>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>alternative-repository</id>
            <name>Maven Alternative Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>alternative2-repository</id>
            <name>Maven Alternative</name>
            <url>https://maven.atlassian.com/3rdparty/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <!--<repository>-->
            <!--<snapshots>-->
                <!--<enabled>false</enabled>-->
            <!--</snapshots>-->
            <!--<id>central</id>-->
            <!--<name>bintray</name>-->
            <!--<url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>-->
        <!--</repository>-->
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Maven Central Repository</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Comment: Mariya Kuznetsova
Have you found resolution of above ? Please share your findings if possible .
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hello Mariya Kuznetsova

Thanks for using our plugin , actualy that plugin is in beta for public , and i'm forgot to add some missing tutorial ,
so inorder to get it work properly , you need to :

1. Add Plugin Repository for Blibli.com Open Source project

   ```
   <pluginRepositories>
   ................... Your other plugin Repositories .............
   <pluginRepository>
       <snapshots>
           <enabled>false</enabled>
       </snapshots>
       <id>bintray-bliblidotcom-maven</id>
       <name>bintray</name>
       <url>https://dl.bintray.com/bliblidotcom/maven</url>
   </pluginRepository>
   ```
2. Add user automation-test (username and name) in your testlink account with role able to create , execute and update testcase , it's used for syncronized to your main testcase repository in testlink and also to update the testcase result it's passed or not

again thank you for using our plugin

Comment: Tried above which you suggested but got below error while running the project :
 https://dl.bintray.com/bliblidotcom/maven/com/blibli/oss/qa/util/cucumber-serenity-testlink-integration/4.0.0/cucumber-serenity-testlink-integration-4.0.0.pom, status: 502 Bad Gateway -> [Help 1]

Please suggest !